# Java - Get username from DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I have a side-project website, where people can comment on stuff , now I need to display user's comments and the username of commenter. The problem is that I can't get a username of logged in user.

Comment Examples :

1)
  **Commented By - Shelo**
    **Test Comment**

2) 
  **Commented By - ProGa**
    **Test Comment 2**

Now, The problem is that If I try to get the "currently logged in" user's username, both comments will have same username when user logges in

```
Authentication loggedInUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String name = loggedInUser.getName();
```

This code example above is how you get currently logged in user. So If I use this code and try to display username by `String name` , and lets say some user logges in with username - **"Davos"**, both comments will look like this - :

1)
  **Commented By - Davos**
    **Test Comment**

2) 
  **Commented By - Davos**
    **Test Comment 2**

What I need is - to get the username of a user who's logged in and if he leaves the comment , display his username. When he logges out or some other user logges in , the "username" of the comment should stay same and must not change depending of who's currently logged in .

[My Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr6tF.png)

> Controller Class (only relevant code):

```
@GetMapping("/foodDescription/{id}")
public String foodDescriptionPage(Model model, @PathVariable(name = "id") String id){
    menuRepository.findById(id).ifPresent(o -> model.addAttribute("menu", o));


    return "food-description";
}

@PostMapping("/postComment/{id}")
public String postComment(@RequestParam String myComment, Model model, @PathVariable(name = "id") String id){

    Optional<Menu> menu = menuRepository.findById(id);
    menuRepository.findById(id).ifPresent(o -> model.addAttribute("menu", o));
    List<Comments> myCommentsList = menu.get().getComments();
    myCommentsList.add(new Comments(myComment));

    menu.get().setComments(myCommentsList);
    menuRepository.save(menu.get());

    return "food-description";
}
```

> food-description.html (Only relevant code for comments section) :

```
    <h3 th:text = "Comments">asd</h3>
<form th:action = "@{/postComment/{myMenuId}(myMenuId=${menu.id})}" method="POST">
    <textarea rows="2" cols="100" name="myComment"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" th:value="Add"/>
</form>

<div class="comment" th:each="com : ${menu.comments}">
    <h3 th:text="Display Commenter's Username here">Commenter's Username</h3>
    <ul>
        <li th:text = "${com.comment}">Comment</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

> User entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_role",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Role role;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_comments",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "comment_id"))
    private List<Comments> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    // Getters/Setters/Constructor
```

}

> Comment entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comments {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "comment")
    private String comment;

    // Getters/Setters/Constructor
```

Comment: This is a fundamental of modeling. You need to add a reference to the `author` of the comment by adding a `userId` property to `comment` entity. Then whenever you need to display the name of the author, you query it from DB

Comment: What Manh said is correct. You already have a `@OneToMany` relation from `User` to `Comments`, all you need is adding a `@ManyToOne` relation from `Comments` to `User`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have to change your data modeling.

For example you can implement something like this:

```
@Entity
public class User {
   @OneToMany()
   public Collection<Comment> comments;
   ...
}

@Entity
public class Comment {
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="user_fk")
   public User user;
   ...
}
```

In this case you have a bidirectional association and you are able to obtain the user form a comment in code (and in the html template). Of course you have to change your DB model too, if you are doing it manually.

Comment: So I added the `@ManyToOne` association and after creating the `comment` it gets added in the DB correctly. But , When I try to access the `user` of a comment by - `comment.getUser().getUserName()` - I get nullPointerException

Comment: And why do I need to change DB model ?

Comment: is there a user_fk column in the comment table in your database?

Comment: Yes . I have association with 
`User->user_role->role`
`Menu->menu_ingredient->ingredients`
`Menu->menu_comments->comments`
`User->user_comments->comments`

Comment: I think I found the right track of getting the username, I'll let you know :)

Comment: Okay I made it :)) So first of all , after printing out all the users with - > `system.out.println(comment.getUser());` I found really weird that some outputs where `null` and some were normal, So I figured that I needed to truncate my tables because the `null` outputs were on the old records (that were added before creating Bidirectional association).

Comment: After truncating tables and creating new records I could bring out the `username` in thymeleaf by `<h3 th:text = ${com.user.userName}></h3>` . If anyone has same problem, keep in mind that I already have a parent loop , where I use `com` as a variable , so you might only wanna use - `${comment.user.userName}` , the basic thing is that you need to loop through `comment` to find `user` and then loop through `user` to find field `userName` . :)